# How to check overlap between two sets of linestrings using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I have two sets of LINESTRINGS, each set containing around 50 LINESTRINGS (which form a road), using PostGIS how do I check whether these two sets overlap or not?

Comment: boolean ST_Overlaps(geometry A, geometry B); see http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Overlaps.html

Answer (score 4):

As simplexio pointed out, the ST_Overlaps function is an excellent start; however, you should check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480320/st-intersects-vs-st-overlaps) that explains some of the nuances and varying behaviours between ST_Overlaps and ST_Intersects - specifically when two geometries are identical.

Here is a query that I use to detect overlaps in a road network - two line geometries that share a line segment. You can remove the t1.id <> t2.id test if you are testing overlaps between two different tables.

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.id <> t2.id
AND ST_Intersects(t1.geom, t2.geom)
AND Upper(ST_GeometryType(ST_Intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom))) LIKE '%LINE%
```